# What is this NLP task called?

Tags: nlp

I am working on a project using NLP and I am trying to do something like this :

[image]

Does anyone know what this kind of tasks is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a semantic lookup, where you look at specific terms in the text and find superordinates for them:
*Chlorpromazine* is a `medicine` or a `drug`; a *diagnosis* is a type of `procedure`, and a *patient* is a `living` being). You could do this with an ontology or a thesaurus; some dictionaries also have information about superordinates, often in the definition ("a *horse* is a *mammal* with four legs").

This is *not* named entity recognition. In NER you identify something by its name, and return a specific identifier. So for *Chlorpromazine* you would not say that it was a medicine/drug, but you would get a serial number or reference for it which is distinct from any other drug.

Comment: I've been looking around and only managed to find articles about why it's important for things like business and SEO and so on. Are there any resources that you could recommend to get started in terms of the tools and algorithms that are used ?

Comment: It depends what exactly your aim is. A simple dictionary lookup might be sufficient; otherwise look for semantic networks and ontologies.

Comment: That'll work thank you